# Externalizing the .ts Angular File. Should not be part of the build

Tags: angular, angular5

We have a angular 5 web application and most of the fields (labels) are dynamically shown from the environment.ts as String Array. There are scenario where we need to add/modify the envioronment.ts labels and automatically that will reflect our UI. Addition/Update of the environment.ts file will be done by the support people according to the user request. The problem we are having is that when we are doing the build all the files are getting bundled into one file that is main.bundle.js and support people find it very difficult to add/modify the labels. Is there any way not to make environment.ts or create a different .ts file which will not be part of the build and should be able to view as normal .ts file (not compressing) so that support people can edit that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`environmnet.ts` is not a good place to add that kind of customizations,

Instead add them as a json file in your assets folder and read from that, then you can simply edit the json file

more info how to read json file [here](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-read-local-json-files-in-angular/)

Comment: Hi RezaRahmati, thanks for the inputs. we will try to implement as above and reply about the outcome.

Comment: Hi RezaRahmati, In environment.ts we have various arrays and there it is been declared as export const envValues = {} but in json we couldn't able to do so. for eg in environment.ts dropdownvalues1 : [{ 'value' : 'Yes'},{ 'value' : 'No'} ],dropdownvalues2 : [{ 'value' : 'Yes'},{ 'value' : 'No'},{ 'value' : 'NA'}], in JSON we are not able to get as key and value as array. please let me know your suggestions

Comment: @vinodkrishna as long as you have a valid json it should be fine, the above values ate valid json `"dropdownvalues1" : [{ "value" : "Yes"},{ "value" : "No"} ],"dropdownvalues2" : [{ "value" : "Yes"},{ "value" : "No"},{ "value' : 'NA"}]` note I changed `'` to `"` and add some. if your issue is not solved, create stackblitz for your issue and ask as new question

Comment: HI RezaRahmati, We are able to read the json file. Another problem we are facing, JSON is not loading in time, in main component (app component) we are trying to load the JSON using services (HttpClient) but actually component ngOnInit function is getting completed and then the JSON loading service is processing after that. Because of that the values are null. I will raise it as a separate question

Comment: @vinodkrishna ok, since this post answers your original question, you can mark it as answer, so other people with same issue will find it as useful

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the same